# ETag Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I noticed that [Feedzirra](http://rdoc.info/projects/pauldix/feedzirra) uses this regex to get the ETag from response header:

```
/.*ETag:\s(.*)\r/
```

Personally I would have written this one:

```
/ETag:\s(.*)\n/
```

Here the questions:

1. Why does it put .* at the beginning even if it is unnecessary (\A is not specified)?
2. Why does it use \r instead of \n? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Completeness I dare say. It's not part of a capture. There may be an implicit start of line anchor though, depending on language and implementation, and in this case it may be necessary.
2. The HTTP spec says that HTTP is to use `"\r\n"` as a line ending. In most programming languages, only `"\n"` is treated as a line ending. The `\r` makes sure that the \r is not swallowed inside the `.*` which would give erroneous whitespace at the end of the capture.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree .* at the beginning is not needed

```
/r and /n are different characters. 

/r = line ending for old macs
/n = line ending for *nix
/r/n = line ending for windows

probably [\r\n] would be best
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s take a look into the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html):

The [*ETag* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) is defined as:

```
ETag = "ETag" ":" entity-tag
```

The [*entitiy-tag*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.11) is defined as:

```
entity-tag = [ weak ] opaque-tag
weak       = "W/"
opaque-tag = quoted-string
```

And [*quoted-string*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2) is defined as:

```
quoted-string  = ( <"> *(qdtext | quoted-pair ) <"> )
```

So the *ETag* header field value may contain a line break. And the correct regular expression would be:

```
/ETag:\s+(?:W\/)?"(?:[ !#-\x7E\x80-\xFF]*|\r\n[\t ]|\\.)*"/
```

Comment: Instead `!#-\x7E\x80-\xFF` i use `\x21\x23-\x7e` due to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3 specification.

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP` [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) mandates CRLF as a linebreak for `HTTP` message. So `\n` would match extra `\r` with properly formatted message:

```
    generic-message = start-line
                      *(message-header CRLF)
                      CRLF
                      [ message-body ]
    start-line      = Request-Line | Status-Line
```

That said, I would make it `[\r\n]` for the sake of robustness.

Comment: Why would \n match \r? They're two different characters.

Comment: No, Rob, of course it won't. I meant that the expression with `\n` instead of `\r` would match `\r` in `.*` part, because it comes before `\n`.